# How to calculate total time taken by a service in java?

Tags: java

I'm running a simple java program using multithreading.  Each thread calls a  service.  I want to print the total time taken for a service call.   Please advise how to do this in multithreading environment.  My code as shown below is not giving the proper result. Please help.

```
public class ServiceCaller {
    private long totalTime;

    public void makeRequest() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        serviceCall()
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = totalTime+(endTime-startTime);
        System.out.println(DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(totalTime))
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not giving proper result"? What is it doing and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: If i calculate total time manually by looking at log file it is different.

Comment: How/Where are you printing the individual times so you can total them?

Comment: I'm accessing totalTime outside ServiceCaller

Comment: So you can only use the last total you print out and you can't add up the total of the totals as that wouldn't mean anything.

Comment: You are printing the running total, so you can't total these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Access to `totalTime` should be [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and [volatile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html). Without syncronisation  different threads will be writing over the value. Without volatile different threads could see different values. You can simplify the access by using the wrapper classes such as [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).

Depending on the platform you are using you may be able to avoid polluting your service class with unrelated timing code with AOP. Most DI frameworks (include [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AOP) and [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)) support this.

Answer (score 1):

Access to totalTime should be thread safe.  You can use an AtomicLong

```
final AtomicLong timeTaken = new AtomicLong(0);

// later
timeTaken.addAndGet(endTime - startTime);
```

You might like to use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` for greater resolution.